# to open a page in new tab using self.location?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `self.location="www.google.com";` in my code to open google page. How can i open same page in another window.

Comment: what are you using is a div click or a href click?? based on we can decide which one to use

Comment: I want to open via script only since i am passing some values in url.

Comment: ram then go for window.open , that should be good in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window)'s [open method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) like so:

```
window.open("www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `<a>` tag and set the `target="_blank"` property to open a page in  anew tab/window. Whether this will be opened in a new tab/windows depends entirely on the settings in the user agent.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
window.open ("www.google.com","mywindow");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function fullwin(targeturl) {
window.open(targeturl,"","fullscreen,scrollbars")
}
</script>

<form>
<input type="button" onClick="fullwin('mypage.html')" value="Show My Frameset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i see at least one freaky method:

```
<a id='newwnd' href='goole.com' style='display:hidden' target='blank'></a>
...
document.getElementById('newwnd').click();
```